# how to get output of a command in cmd into a text area

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc

I am using Java and using `Scanner` class. I'll take an SQL query as input and store it into `String s`.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String s=sc.nextLine();
```

I want to execute this string (query) and display the result obtained in SQL command line in a text area in swings.

For example if the input is

```
update emp set no=526 where id='abc'
```

then the text area should display:

> 1 row(s) updated

and similarly whatever is displayed in the SQL command line for any query.

BASICALLY OUTPUT OF COMMAND LINE SHOULD BE REDIRECTED TO TEXT AREA

Comment: How do execute your sql query ? it's important to know how the response is received

Comment: i m using the object of ResultSet but if you have any other way of doing it i'll do it happily provided it solves my problem

Comment: you execute a query via a JDBC call, that's a good way. But you expect to have a result that a tool (the sql command line) gives you. So i think the answer of Benito is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDBC to access the DB, you could do something like this:

```
// Create the UPDATE statement
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("update emp set no=? where id=?");
pstmt.setLong(1, 526L);
pstmt.setString(2, "abc");

// Execute it
int rowCount = pstmt.executeUpdate();
// You receive as result the count of modified rows
...
// And then update the textArea
textArea.setText(String.format("%d row(s) updated", rowCount));
```

Comment: its not a standard method.Basically the output displayed in SQL command line should be redirected to Text area